# Why would people use ThreadPoolExecutor instead of direct function call?

Tags: python

this code (snippet_1) is adapted from [ThreadPoolExecutor Example in doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))

print('after')
```

which works well, and gets

> 'http://www.foxnews.com/' page is 990869 bytes 'http://www.cnn.com/'
>   page is 990869 bytes 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/' page is 990869 bytes
>   'http://europe.wsj.com/' page is 990869 bytes after

this code is my own (snippet_2) to implement the same job with direct function call.

```
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/']
for url in URLS:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=60) as conn:
        print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))

print('after')
```

snippet_1 seems to be more common, but why?

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor is an Executor subclass that uses a pool of threads to execute calls asynchronously.` the last word is the key. Read a bit about `async`. Your snipper is concurrent, which is not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are reading things from a network, your application will probably spend most of its time waiting on a reply.

Normally, the Global Interpreter Lock inside CPython (the Python implementation you are probably using) ensures that only one thread at a time is executing Python bytecode.

But when waiting for I/O (including network I/O) the GIL is released giving other threads opportunity to run. That means that multiple reads are effectively running in parallel instead of one after another, shortening overall execution time.

For a handful of URI's that won't make much of a difference. But the more URI's you use, the more noticable it gets.

So the `ThreadPoolExecutor` is mainly useful for running I/O operations in parallel. The `ProcessPoolExecutor` on the other hand is useful for running CPU intensive tasks in parallel. Since it uses multiple processes, the restriction of the GIL doesn't apply.